# How to Set Up a Test for the Destroy Method Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-testing

I'm going through the testing on my app, and I've gotten to the point where I need to test the destroy method of my controller. The test as I have it currently is:

```
public function test_user_can_delete_draft()
{
  $user = factory(User::class)->states('confirmed', 'normaluser')->create();
  $userForm = factory(Form::class)->states('in_house_signs')->create(['user_id' => $user->id, 'status' => 'draft',]);
  // Test creator can delete form
  $response = $this->actingAs($user)->delete(route('forms.destroy', $userForm));
  $response->assertSuccessful();
}
```

And the method in the controller that I am testing is:

```
public function destroy($id) {
   $form = Form::find($id);
   Comment::where('form_id', $id)->delete();
   $form->delete();

   // Redirect
   return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Form successfully deleted');
}
```

When I run phpunit, I get the error:

```
Response status code [302] is not a successful status code.
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

What should I do to get the test to run properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try to use `assertRedirect` https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/http-tests#assert-redirect

or use the status check:

`$response->assertStatus(302)` https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/http-tests#assert-status

or if you really want to check if the record is being deleted you could check the database in your test if the record is deleted `$this->assertEquals(Comment::where('form_id', $userForm->id)->first(),null)`

Comment: I changed my controller from redirect()->back to redirect()->route and changed the test to match and now it passes! Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$response->assertSuccessful();` and redirecting user, I mean if your delete request successes it will return 302 redirect, change `assertSuccessful()` to `assertStatus(302)`